# Is it good to have separate home page or just hyperlink of logo?

Tags: homepage

In my website the logo is linked to home page. should I add a home page link in menu too?

Answer (score 2):

Nielsen/Norman Group [researched this](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/homepage-links/) and their answer is: provide both.

> It is great if your site logo offers a one-click approach to navigating to your homepage. But don’t stop there. While more people than ever have learned to click on the logo to go to the homepage, many users still look for an actual Home link.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Logo as homepage link is standard website practice.  There's no need to duplicate.